# Multiple failed ST-LINK/V2

Tags: st-link, st, stm8

I have been using a ST-LINK/V2 for a project that uses a STM8 microcontroller. The ST-LINK is connected to the microcontroller using the 4 pin SWIM port. The microcontroller is powered from an isolated 5V supply.

After a couple of days of debugging, the ST-LINK started causing my USB port to go into overcurrent protection. I bought another ST-LINK which I used without issue for a few days then started getting the same issue.

I took a look inside the failed debuggers and the 5V rail was a dead short to GND. I replaced the 3.3V regulators and both ST-LINKs are working again.

What could cause this issue? I contacted ST support but they just advised me I could buy a replacement from their website which wasn't particularly helpful. I've verified the target power supply never gets close to the 5.5V limit of the ST-LINK. As the target supply is isolated there shouldn't be any large currents through the GND connection.

Comment: Are you talking about the complete packaged-in-injection-molded-case ST-LINK/V2 product, or the integrated STLINK that's on various dev boards?

Comment: user2248702 - Hi (a) (Similar to what another site member has asked while I've been typing) Are these genuine ST-LINK/V2 bought from an ST distributor? Or one of the not-quite-clones sold on other sites (*some* look very similar)? (b) Can you [edit] the question and add a schematic of (i) your hardware and (ii) how the ST-LINK & power is connected, so we can see how it all fits together. (c) You said "*After a couple of days of debugging*" the ST-LINK stops working normally. Has that happened, every couple of days, since you started debugging with it? Or was it OK for a while at the start?

Comment: please add a diagram or schematic

Comment: I'm using the plastic cased ST-LINK/V2 purchased from DigiKey. I'll have to make a simplified version of the schematic as I'm not sure if I'm able to show the full thing, but in essence it's a 5V linear regulator powering a STM8 with a couple of decoupling capacitors and the reset and SWIM data lines going directly to the debug header. Both times the ST-LINK survived around 2 days of continuous use before having the regulator fail dead short.

Comment: @user2248702 - Thanks for the update. That eliminates some concerns I had. If the ST-LINKs had ever survived longer than a few days, I would be asking "what changed just before the failures started". || Understood that full schematics may not be possible for commercial reasons - but without full schematics, any simplification of them might (unknowingly) hide the one detail that other people see and makes them recognise the problem :( || There must be *something* "wrong" with the config (otherwise the regulators wouldn't be failing!) but I would need to see the setup :( || Sincere good luck!